# AlarmClock says "xx" hours set from now

Tags: java, android, android-studio

While adding the alarm time form the user input (numberpicker) .

Like 1 hour , 0 minute is set to add to current time 1:53 PM , gives 2:53 PM

Then it says "alarm is set for 13 hours form now" ,and adds the alarm .

```
set.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                c.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hrs.getValue());
                c.add(Calendar.MINUTE, mins.getValue());
                Calendar opt = c;


                SimpleDateFormat time = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
                String timeformat = time.format(opt.getTime());

                String splitTime[] = timeformat.split(":");

                int hour = Integer.parseInt(splitTime[0]);
                int minute = Integer.parseInt(splitTime[1]);

                op.setText("OP:" + timeformat);

                Intent s = new Intent (AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);

                s.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, minute);
                s.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, hour);
                s.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_SKIP_UI, true);
                s.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                startActivity(s);

            }
```

But the correct one should say "alarm is set 1 hour from now".. Dont know why it acts like this ..

Anyone help me..

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer your looking for as I'm not familiar with android. However, I have a theory that the time is stored in a 24-hour format. In which you may be thinking the time is is being set to 2pm(14:00) but is actually 2am(02:00). In which you have not added 12hours for the PM time change.